# Reaching a numeric value in an xml line

Tags: c#, xml

I have this line of code here :

```
foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
{
    DataRow r = table.NewRow();
    r["Date"] = item.PublishDate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    r["Publish Time"] = item.PublishDate.TimeOfDay;
    r["Event"] = item.Title.Text;
    table.Rows.Add(r);
}
```

and this xml (rss feed) 'description' line :

```
<description>
    <table cellspacing='5' border='0'> 
        <tr> 
            <th>Time Left</th> 
            <th>Impact</th> 
            <th>Previous</th> 
            <th>Consensus</th> 
            <th>Actual</th> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>1h 17min</td> 
            <td><img src="http://www.myfxbook.com/images/transparent.png" class="sprite sprite-common sprite-medium-impact"/></td> 
            <td> 111.0 </td> 
            <td> 111.0 </td> 
            <td> </td> 
        </tr> 
    </table>
</description>
```

and I need to retrieve the values(numeric or strings) that match 'Impact' 'Previous' ' Consensus' and 'Actual' columns in this table presented in the xml line. 
and then import it into the data table rows as I have done in the c# code.
any efficient way to do this?

Comment: The best you can do, is using an existing html parser, instead of parse it yourself or using regex.

Comment: Please also read how to format: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example for your specific XML (what appears to be a 2-row HTML table with headers and values; matching number of columns in both rows):

You can extract and pair the values using `XDocument` and LINQ:

```
//Parse data - in this example, stored in a string
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(data);

//Select table rows (tr elements)
var tableRows = from tr in xDoc.Descendants("tr")
                select tr;

//Extract column headings
var headings = from th in tableRows.Descendants("th")
               select th.Value;

//Extract column data
var values = from td in tableRows.Descendants("td")
             select td.Value;

//Create pairs; can be adapted to other types, such as C# 7 tuples, a Dictionary, etc.
var pairs = Enumerable.Zip(headings, values, (name, value) 
    => new Tuple<string, string>(name, value));
```

You can then access the data as you like (including storing it in the database) directly from the "pairs" collection.

Comment: XDocument.Parse(data)  :  'data' will be the rss URL ?

Comment: @Jonathan, no, data is a string; but you can obtain it from URL, for instance `string data = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);`

Comment: thanks a lot, 
although xDoc gets the data, tablerows, heading and values appear empty

Comment: Did you try the DataSet method ReadXML()?

Comment: @CoolBots  thanks a lot, although xDoc gets the data, tablerows, heading and values appear empty

Comment: @Jonathan my code is based on and tested against your example xml - if you review my answer and your implementation of it, you should be able to figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

@CoolBots, here is a console application to simple things :

```
    string data = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.myfxbook.com/rss/forex-economic-calendar-events");
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(data);

        //selecting table rows
        var tablerows = from tr in xdoc.Descendants("tr")
                        select tr;


        //extarct the headers
        var headings = from th in tablerows.Descendants("th")
                       select th.Value;
        //extract column data 
        var values = from td in tablerows.Descendants("td")
                     select td.Value;
        //Creating pairs
        var pairs = Enumerable.Zip(headings, values, (name, value)
                     => new Tuple<string, string>(name, value));

        foreach(var item in values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: headings , values, and tablerows don't seem to receive data for some reason